# What will beselenium webdriver identifier for flipkart login button in java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

webdriver is throwing the element not found exception when trying to login to flipkart using webdriver. 
need the valid identifier for flipkart login button

1. Navigate to http://www.flipkart.com/
2. CLick on login button on the top right hand corner
3. Notice the login button in the popup

Comment: i was trying with the class value. as the class name is two different words, it was giving compund class error. 
class="btn btn-blue"

By.xpath("//li[@class='no-border']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("login_email_id")).sendKeys("email_id");
driver.findElement(By.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Login'][type='submit']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while trying to automate the Flipkart login page in Chrome using selenium.

Sadly for me none of the online suggestions worked, I tried
1. GetWindowHandle way
2. Passing parameters directly to the page using http://user:pass@host.com
3. Tried to check for multiple frames

Finally what worked was, I copied the "Driver.FindElement & WebElement.Click" code twice, Basically the problem was the Login popup window was getting closed after the first click due to which the element was not found.

This seems to be a machine/version specific issue with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Sample below:

```
//Click on 'Login'
driver.FindElement(By.Css(".js-login")).Click()
//Enter email
driver.FindElement(By.Css("#login_email_id")).sendKeys('emailvalue');
//Enter pswd
driver.FindElement(By.Css("#login_password")).sendKeys('password');
//press on login button
driver.FindElement(By.Css("#login-dialog .btn[value='Login']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WebDriver wb = new InternetExplorerDriver();
wb.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
wb.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='container']/div/div/header/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[8]/a[contains(text(),'Log In')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

driver.findElement(By.className("_2zrpKA")).sendKeys(" YOUR USER NAME");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("YOUR PASSWORD");

driver.findElement(By.className("_2zrpKA")).submit();
```